# Installing Windows 8.1 from external hdd - enters to loop

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 from external hdd using this:
http://www.intowindows.com/install-windows-8-from-external-hard-drive/

but after that step:

[image]

it does restart and then go again to the start of the install, like nothing happend before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to then unplug your external hard drive, after it's booted past the BIOS, you can then plug it back in

Comment: I changed the BIOS to the hdd I install on and it works